# Wny can't I control Chrome Selenium Web Driver under Internet disconnect [WebDriver Exception]

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Chrome Web Driver.
Automation test is no problem.

But, I also have to test exception case.
Only Internet disconnect case is problem.

[pre-condition]

1. Run my automation app.
2. Turn off wifi connection during normal operation.
3. I saw `"ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED"` message  on chrome browser.
4. After 1 minute `"OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException"` occurred
   As far as I know, The HTTP request to the remote Web Driver timed out
   after 60 seconds
5. I caught exception with using try~catch, But, After that, I can't
   control chrome web driver.I mean, I'll send command s `_driver.Quit()`,
   `_driver.Close()`,`_driver.URL()`..etc. No API calls are carried out.

   ```
   do {
       try {
         _driver.FindElement(By.XPath(composeXPath)).Click();
         _driver.Navigate().Back();
       } catch (System.Net.WebException e) {
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[Web Actor]WebException expired");

       } catch (OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException e) {
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[Web Actor]WebDriverException");
         _driver.Quit();
       }
     } while (exit_flag == false);
   }
   ```

Is this basic concept in webdriver or normal operation?
You can make this exception case easily. 
If you  meet the same experience, Help me. 
Before Wifi on and reload url from chrome browser, I can't any access
to chrome WEB Driver.
I'm going to go away.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void disConnectInternet() throws IOException {
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("offline", true);
    map.put("latency", 5);
    map.put("download_throughput", 500);
    map.put("upload_throughput", 1024);


    CommandExecutor executor = ((ChromeDriver)driver).getCommandExecutor();
    Response response = executor.execute(
            new Command(((ChromeDriver)driver).getSessionId(), "setNetworkConditions", ImmutableMap.of("network_conditions", ImmutableMap.copyOf(map))));
}
```